# git submodules defined by Carthage not being fetched

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, ios-frameworks, carthage

I have used Carthage to import several frameworks as git submodules. For reference the repo is available on [github](https://github.com/maximveksler/IKnowKungFu).

Carthage created a mix of configurations resulting in failure of building freshly cloned copy:

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) carthage update
*** Fetching Nimble
*** Fetching Quick
*** Fetching CleanroomLogger
*** Fetching CleanroomASL
Parse error: expected submodule commit SHA in output of task (ls-tree -z HEAD Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomLogger) but encountered:
```

Fresh clone of the repo gives the following:

- `Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble` and
- `Carthage/Checkouts/Quick`

exist but are empty folders.

After running `git submodule update --init --recursive`:

- `Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble` and
- `Carthage/Checkouts/Quick` and
- `Carthage/Checkouts/Quick/Externals/Nimble`

are checked out. Yet no memory of:

- `Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomASL` and
- `Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomLogger`

**Cartfile**

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) cat Cartfile
github "emaloney/CleanroomLogger"
```

**Cartfile.private**

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) cat Cartfile.private
github "Quick/Quick"
github "Quick/Nimble"
```

**.gitmodules**

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) cat .gitmodules
[submodule "Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomASL"]
    url = https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomASL.git
[submodule "Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomLogger"]
    path = Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomLogger
    url = https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomLogger.git
[submodule "Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble"]
    path = Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble
    url = https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git
[submodule "Carthage/Checkouts/Quick"]
    path = Carthage/Checkouts/Quick
    url = https://github.com/Quick/Quick.git
```

**.gitignore**

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) cat .gitignore
###
### https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore
###

# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData/

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata/

## Other
*.moved-aside
*.xccheckout
*.xcscmblueprint

## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap
*.ipa

## Playgrounds
timeline.xctimeline
playground.xcworkspace

# Swift Package Manager
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Swift Package Manager dependencies.
# Packages/
.build/

# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control
#
# Pods/

# Carthage
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Carthage dependencies.
Carthage/Checkouts

Carthage/Build

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/docs/Gitignore.md

fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/screenshots


###
### https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/OSX.gitignore
###

.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

#### Update 1

Further research show Carthage updated the .gitmodules entries for `Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomASL` and `Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomLogger` but did failed to create the [160000](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) directory pointers to allow cloning the submodules.

Nothing that I do seems to be able to resolve this. Including

- manually removing the Cleanroom entries from .gitmodules
- wiping the local Carthage folder
- `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit`

I'm clueless about how to fix this.

#### Update 2

Filed a bug report https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1146

Comment: You shouldn't need to recursively init your submodules, a simple `git submodule update --init` should be enough.

Comment: @Abizern sadly this does not pull the Cleanroom stuff, if you look at the repo structure on github it seems that folders haven't been created for these submodules which leaves them in limbo state. For some reason I can't convince carthage for just forget about Cleanroom stuff and OTOH none of the git submodule update --init commands seems be able to fetch the missing projects.

Comment: After reading [drosenstark's comments on 1146](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1146), I am uncertain if this was a problem with your config? A problem with Carthage? Or both? Since 1146 is now closed, can you answer this question?

Comment: I think it was an issue with my repo, that got to this state. Carthage is the tool that got my repo into this state. So it's a matter of definition of who's issue it is. If you can be more specific about what you are wishing to know then perhaps I'll be to able reply with further info

Comment: @MaximVeksler I vaguely recall a problem I was having with git + Carthage 4 days ago, but now I do not know exactly what it was. In any case, this question helped me along the way.